# MSSQL order by previous 7 days

Tags: sql-server

I run this query in MSSQL to get the items, grouping by the last 7 days of the week:

```
SELECT COUNT(Date_Entered), DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered)  
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Board_Name = 'Board'
      AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Entered,GETDATE()) <= 7
  GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered)
```

In the result, days of the week are sorted in alphabetical order: Friday > Monday > Saturday > Sunday > Thursday > Tuesday > Wednesday

How do I sort by the normal/correct/common sense order, starting with the weekday of 7 days ago and ending with yesterday?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Entered,GETDATE()) <= 7` isn't sargeable and won't scale very well.  You should consider using `Date_Entered >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering by `MAX(Date_Entered)` should work too:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Date_Entered), 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered)  
FROM my_table
WHERE Board_Name = 'Board' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Entered,GETDATE()) <= 7
GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered)
ORDER BY MAX(Date_Entered);
```

Normally you would want to order by the date ascending, but since you use an aggregate function you would need to group by the date which would ruin it, but since the max(date) in every group is the date you can do max(date) to order.

Comment: That only works if you have data covering every day.

Comment: @shawnt00 Not following, please explain. Why wouldn't it work with missing dates?

Comment: The most recent Saturday in the data could have been three weeks ago but he still wants Saturday to be first even if there more recent data on other days of the week.

Comment: @shawnt00 That's not how I understood the question, but I guess that might be a valid interpretation. I thought the datediff condition was meant to limit to the previous seven days and that _grouping by the last 7 days of the week_ meant just that, and not last available Saturday data and forward.

Answer (score 1):

DATEPART is your friend, try it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Date_Entered), DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered),DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Entered)  
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Board_Name = 'Board'
      AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Date_Entered,GETDATE()) <= 7
  GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Entered),DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date_Entered)
ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Entered)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't count on data being available for every week then you'd need to do something more based on date calculations. Off the top of my head I think this will be more reliable:

```
ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(dd, MAX(Date_Entered), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 77777) % 7
```

EDIT: I wrote that not realizing that the data was already limited to a single week. I thought the intention was to group in buckets by day of week for a longer range of dates.

I'll also comment that to me it is more natural to do the grouping on `cast(Date_Entered as date)` rather than on a string value and I wouldn't be surprised if it's a more efficient query.